# Weird sorting issue with bubble sort using ASM inline assembly (64 bit)

Tags: c, sorting, gcc, assembly

I'm currently doing inline ASM assembly (I think) with C on a 64-bit machine. At least for gcc, I'm supposed to compile using gcc -Wall -masm=intel name.c -o name. Anyways, we have to implement a bubble sort using certain specifications.

Mainly the template is supposed to look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define ARRAY_LENGTH 20

int main()
{
    int array[ARRAY_LENGTH];
    int i;
    int swapped;

    printf("Enter the elements one by one \n");
    for (i = 0; i < ARRAY_LENGTH; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &array[i]);
    }

    printf("Input array elements \n");
    for (i = 0; i < ARRAY_LENGTH ; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", array[i]);
    }

    /*  Bubble sorting begins */
    do
    {
        swapped = 0;
        /*
        for (i = 1; i < ARRAY_LENGTH; i++)
        {
            if (array[i] < array [i-1])
            {
                swapped = 1;
                int temp = array [i-1];
                array [i-1] = array [i];
                array[i] = temp;
            }
        }
        */
        __asm__ __volatile__(";"                              //use up to 20 inst.
                             :"+r" (swapped)                  //don't touch this line 
                             :"b" (array), "a" (ARRAY_LENGTH) //don't touch this line
                             :"memory"                        //include other clobbered regs
                             );

    } while (swapped > 0);

    printf("Sorted array is...\n");
    for (i = 0; i < ARRAY_LENGTH; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", array[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Basically we are supposed to implement the for loop in assembly, as well as the swap code. For the swap we are supposed to use an xor algorithm. Here is my assembly code:

```
__asm__ __volatile__(   "mov rsi, 0;"
                                "FOR:" // start for loop
                                "add rsi, 1;"   
                                "cmp rsi, rax;" // is rsi > array length (i < length?)
                                "jg END_FOR;" // if so jump to end of for loop
                                // else carry on with for loop, set values for a[i]/a[i-1]
                                "mov ecx, dword ptr [rbx + 4 * rsi];"
                                "mov edx, dword ptr [rbx + 4 * (rsi - 1)];" // set the values to ecx,edx
                                "cmp ecx, edx;" // a[i] > a[i-1]? jmp to done, else
                                "jg DONE;"
                                // swap
                                "xor ecx, edx;"
                                "xor edx, ecx;"
                                "xor ecx, edx;" // swap complete
                                // store values back into memory
                                "mov dword ptr [rbx + 4 * rsi], ecx;" // new ecx
                                "mov dword ptr [rbx + 4 * rsi - 4], edx;" // new edx
                                "mov %0, 1;"
                                "DONE:" // end else // increment counter
                                "jmp FOR;" // jump back to start of for loop
                                "END_FOR:"
                                : "+r" (swapped)        // don't touch this line [output]
                                : "b" (array), "a" (ARRAY_LENGTH) // dont touch this line [input]
                                : "memory", "cc", "rsi", "ecx", "edx"           // include other clobbered reg
                             );
```

The problem is my code is doing some very weird sorting things. For some reason, a certain set of values will give me back an almost sorted array. Other times, the program continues in an infinite loop :| My teacher looked it over and had no idea what was going wrong with it, and I don't really know either to be honest.

For example, using this input:

```
11
-11
12
-12
13
-13
14
-14
15
-15
16
-16
17
-17
18
-18
19
-19
20
-20
```

yields this result:

```
-20
-19
-18
-17
-16
-15
-14
-13
-12
-11
0
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
```

While using this input:

```
100
90
80
70
60
50
40
30
20
10
0
-10
-20
-30
-40
-50
-60
-70
-80
-90
```

just continues in an infinite loop :/ Even weirder, the guy next to me literally copied off of me, except used different registers for assigning his values, and his program worked correctly. Anyone have any idea what to do?

Comment: This runs correctly for me.  Other than some minor inefficiency, I'm not seeing anything wrong.  Could this be environmental?  What build of gcc are you using?  How are you running the code?  Perhaps you should be using -o name.exe?

Comment: The lab server at my school is using gcc (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-11). And I'm running the code after doing the gcc line with just ./bubble_sort

Comment: OffTopic: The XOR swap code isn't needed. You have both values in registers, just store them to the correct memory locations.

Comment: OnTopic: The line `jg END_FOR` should be `jge END_FOR` since the opposite of `<` is `>=`

Comment: The jge was it :| Thanks for that! and I asked the professor about that as well, but he told us we had to still implement a xor swap :/

Answer (score 0):

The line `jg END_FOR` should be `jge END_FOR` since the opposite of `<` is `>=` –  user3386109